# How to tag nodes in GKE, then assign pods to nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the standard 3-nodes pool in GKE.

I want to label 1 of these nodes to be something like `dev` or `test`, so all the pods in the namespace `dev`, `qa` or `stage` are loaded in that node, preferrably.

The pods in the namespace `prod` would use the other available nodes, be it 2, 3 or more nodes available.

Basically I want to restrict the CPU / memory load for non-important deployments to affect the `prod` deployments.

How can I do this automatically? Because when Google updates the nodes (for a software update) a new one is created.

Comment: You mention in a comment below that processes from one environment are killing off nodes, which is impacting other environments; would it make more sense to run these environments in separate clusters?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict CPU/memory, using labels on nodes is not the right way to do this. Instead, set a quota on the dev/test namespace.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/

Basically, it would look something like this

```
apiVersion: v1
  kind: ResourceQuota
  metadata:
    name: low-priority
  spec:
    hard:
      cpu: "5"
      memory: 1Gi
      pods: "10"
```

I have a blog post about this as well: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits

Edit:

If you really want to do this, I think the best way would be to use [node pools](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools), and then [tag the pods to go into a specific pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools#deploy).

Comment: Thanks, we've been having random nodes reboots... so I'm wondering if that's caused by NFS Server we have as pod... so we want to avoid a QA / DEV / STAGE deploy killing the node where PROD is living...

Comment: @JorgeeFG I made an edit to my answer, but if thats the case the best thing to do is use node pools, or even better would just be to create two GKE clusters. With two clusters, there is zero risk.